# Login error message redirect to checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

My login page after submit it redirect to checkout page. if i enter wrong password it redirect to checkout page and then error message also throw in checkout page only. How i fix it.

```
<div class="account-login">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="col2-set">
            <div class="col-1 new-users">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Customers') ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.') ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 registered-users">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Registered Customers') ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li>
                            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>

                </div>
                 <div class="buttons-set">
                    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
                    <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if (Mage::helper('checkout')->isContextCheckout()): ?>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

After Login also it redirect to checkout page.

Comment: What is the out put of `<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>"`...

Answer (score 0):

The redirecting is done from your controller that the form is posting to.

Take a look at your form action (`<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>`)  url, the navigate to the corresponding controller redirect logic

Comment: this is my form action in browser <form action="https://videomergerapp.com/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post" id="login-form">